# Wikipedia API Interlanguage Links using WMF Labs

Tags: python, translation, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I'm working through WMF Labs and using the Wikipedia API to parse out all the page links from a specific page in German then go back and find the english equivalent. My code only works for batches of 5 or less. If I try to run a larger batch like 10 or 15, some of the links that I KNOW have an english equivalent (good old fashioned search, also they show up in the <5 batches) throwback "None" as the english equivalent. Why do all links only work in batches of less than 5?

Here is a link to my code.

https://github.com/empo0270/Interlanguage-links-Wiki/blob/master/translateOutlinks.py

Answer (score 1):

The API returns a maximum number of links per query, in this case 500 due to the `lllimit=500` in your request. To get the remaining links, you have to follow the instructions for [continuing queries](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Continuing_queries) to submit additional requests.

Since you're using python, you might want to consider using [pywikibot](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot) which handles many of these details for you.